# Invalid entry point for shader when using HLSL->SPIR-V->OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, spir-v, shaderc

I am trying to implement a system so that I can use HLSL in my OpenGL application, since it can be compiled to SPIR-V, and SPIR-V can be translated to something that works with e.g DirectX.

However, I receive an error when specializing the shader:

```
glSpecializeShaderARB("vert" is not a valid entry point for shader)
```

I am using `shaderc.net`, and compiling to SPIR-V via that, then following standard procedure, I've attached the SPIR-V source code to a shader object.

```cs
ShaderHandle shaderHandle = GL.CreateShader(source.GLShaderType);
GL.ShaderBinary(Utility.Wrap(shaderHandle), ShaderBinaryFormat.ShaderBinaryFormatSpirV, result.CodePointer, (int)result.CodeLength);
GL.SpecializeShader(shaderHandle, source.EntryPoint, 0, Array.Empty<uint>(), Array.Empty<uint>());
```

The `result` variable, is just the compilation result from shaderc, and Utility.Wrap is what I use to simply convert a single variable to a ReadOnlySpan.

I'll append that I am using OpenTK for the OpenGL bindings.

I've tried a variety of shader sources. This one actually decompiles into what seems like valid GLSL in RenderDoc:

```
struct VERTEX_DATA
{
    float3 pos;
};

float4 vert(VERTEX_DATA vertex) : SV_POSITION
{
    return float4(vertex.pos, 0);
}
```

Here's the output from the RenderDoc decompiler

```c
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_pos, 0.0);
}
```

which seems like valid GLSL, but it results in the error I've specified.

EDIT:
There was a request for dissasembly. Here's RenderDoc SPIR-V disasm

```
; SPIR-V
; Version: 1.0
; Generator: Google Shaderc over Glslang; 11
; Bound: 47
; Schema: 0
               OpCapability Shader
          %2 = OpExtInstImport "GLSL.std.450"
               OpMemoryModel Logical GLSL450
               OpEntryPoint Vertex %vert "vert" %vertex_pos %_entryPointOutput
          %1 = OpString "test.hlsl"
               OpSource HLSL 500 %1 "// OpModuleProcessed entry-point vert
// OpModuleProcessed client opengl100
// OpModuleProcessed target-env opengl
// OpModuleProcessed hlsl-offsets
#line 1
struct VERTEX_DATA
{
    float3 pos;
};

float4 vert(VERTEX_DATA vertex) : SV_POSITION
{
    return float4(vertex.pos, 0);
}"
               OpSourceExtension "GL_GOOGLE_cpp_style_line_directive"
               OpSourceExtension "GL_GOOGLE_include_directive"
               OpName %vert "vert"
               OpName %vertex_pos "vertex.pos"
               OpName %_entryPointOutput "@entryPointOutput"
               OpDecorate %vertex_pos Location 0
               OpDecorate %_entryPointOutput BuiltIn Position
       %void = OpTypeVoid
          %4 = OpTypeFunction %void
      %float = OpTypeFloat 32
    %v3float = OpTypeVector %float 3
    %v4float = OpTypeVector %float 4
    %float_0 = OpConstant %float 0
%_ptr_Input_v3float = OpTypePointer Input %v3float
 %vertex_pos = OpVariable %_ptr_Input_v3float Input
%_ptr_Output_v4float = OpTypePointer Output %v4float
%_entryPointOutput = OpVariable %_ptr_Output_v4float Output
               OpLine %1 7 1
       %vert = OpFunction %void None %4
               OpNoLine
          %6 = OpLabel
               OpLine %1 7 0
         %31 = OpLoad %v3float %vertex_pos
               OpLine %1 8 0
         %43 = OpCompositeExtract %float %31 0
         %44 = OpCompositeExtract %float %31 1
         %45 = OpCompositeExtract %float %31 2
         %46 = OpCompositeConstruct %v4float %43 %44 %45 %float_0
               OpLine %1 7 0
               OpStore %_entryPointOutput %46
               OpReturn
               OpFunctionEnd
```

Comment: "*I am using shaderc.net,*" Is it able to generate SPIR-V that can be used with OpenGL?

Comment: SPIR-V is standardized. It is also capable of compiling GLSL into SPIR-V, so I don't see why not. Whilst SPIR-V was designed for Vulkan, OpenGL *should* be completely compatible. Reading through the [SPIR-V page on the OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V#Mapping_to_GLSL) states nothing that would point to compatability issues. I'd like to note I'm using SPIR-V 1.0, as I am unsure of anything above 1.0.

Comment: "*Whilst SPIR-V was designed for Vulkan, OpenGL should be completely compatible.*" Vulkan and OpenGL have fundamentally different resource models (ie: how you expose resources to be accessed by shaders). As such, a SPIR-V module that works on Vulkan will not necessarily work on OpenGL and vice-versa. OpenGL doesn't have descriptor sets, and Vulkan doesn't know what to do with OpenGL binding indices. SPIR-V may be standardized, but the APIs consuming it are not compatible. So compilers targeting SPIR-V need to know if they are generating code meant for Vulkan or OpenGL.

Comment: It's best to look at the generated SPIR-V, not decompiled into GLSL, but disassembled into SPIR-V assembly opcodes.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am explicitly telling the compiler the target platform is OpenGL 4.5 too, if that clears stuff up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by simply not using `shaderc.net`. For whatever reason(which I do not know) it doesn't seem to work properly. However, as soon as I switched to `Vortice.ShaderCompiler` which pretty much just was a slot-in alternative, some different naming conventions and that's it, it suddenly worked perfectly.

So, I guess the answer is:
Don't use shaderc.net, it is broken and hasn't been maintained in 3 years, use something up-to-date instead, there are some nice alternatives.